# Importing native methods in Xamarin.Mac

Tags: xamarin, interop, marshalling, dllimport, xamarin.mac

I'm looking for a way to use `SCNetworkInterfaceCopyAll` in my Xamarin.Mac app.
I've imported it

```
[DllImport("/System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration")]
public static extern IntPtr SCNetworkInterfaceCopyAll();
```

Then I get an array by calling `var array = NSArray.ArrayFromHandle<NSObject>(pointer)`.
But can't figure out how to get values from the output array of SCNetworkInterface. I've tried to marshal it as

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Test
{
    IntPtr interface_type;
    IntPtr entity_hardware;
}
```

And then call `Marshal.PtrToStructure<Test>(i.Handle)` but it gives random pointers instead of meaningful values.

Comment: Did you get any luck to extract values from SCNetworkInterfaceCopyAll() ?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya, unfortunately, I don't remember if I managed to fix it.

Comment: No issue, I solved it. Posting it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the information provided from `System.Net.NetworkInformation. NetworkInterface` (or do you need actually need a `SCNetworkInterface`?)

#### `Xamarin.Mac` Example:

```
foreach (NetworkInterface nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
{
    if (nic.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
        Console.WriteLine(nic.GetPhysicalAddress());
}
```

Comment: No, I need to know which interface is WiFi but unfortunately GetAllNetworkInterfaces for some reason return WiFi interface as Ethernet.

Comment: @ArturShamsutdinov What info do you need once you have the wireless interface?

Comment: Basically my goal is to return list of active Ethernet interfaces with MAC addresses excluding WiFi interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at SCNetworkConfiguration.h it appears there are a number of C APIs you are to call on your IntPtr to retrieve the specific information you need.

CoreFoundation APIs often return "baton" pointers that you need to pass to other functions. Where did you see that struct definition?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Objective-C methods in Xamarin to get the MAC Address as C# gives a different MAC Address:

```
[DllImport("/System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration")]
public static extern IntPtr SCNetworkInterfaceCopyAll();

[DllImport("/System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration")]
public static extern IntPtr SCNetworkInterfaceGetHardwareAddressString(IntPtr scNetworkInterfaceRef);

private string MacAddress()
{
        string address = string.Empty;

        using (var interfaces = Runtime.GetNSObject<NSArray>(SCNetworkInterfaceCopyAll()))
        {
            for (nuint i = 0; i < interfaces.Count; i++)
            {
                IntPtr nic = interfaces.ValueAt(i);
                var addressPtr = SCNetworkInterfaceGetHardwareAddressString(nic);

                address = Runtime.GetNSObject<NSString>(addressPtr);

                if (address != null) break;
            }
        }
        return address;
}
```